# Decoding audio data of Mediarecorder is failed on chrome

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, web-mediarecorder

I using MediaRecorder to record microphone. The default format of MediaRecorder in chrome is video/webm. Here is short example:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true,video: false})
        .then(function(stream) {
            var recordedChunks = [];
            var recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            recorder.start(10);

            recorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {
                if (event.data.size > 0) {
                    recordedChunks.push(event.data);
                } else {
                    // ...
                }
            }

            setTimeout(function(){
                recorder.stop();
                var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
                  "type": recordedChunks[0].type
                });

                var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                var context = new AudioContext();
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("GET", blobUrl, true);
                request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

                request.onload = function () {
                context.decodeAudioData(
                    request.response,
                    function (buffer) {
                        if (!buffer) {
                            alert("buffer is empty!");
                        }

                        var dataArray = buffer.getChannelData(0);

                        //process channel data...

                        context.close();
                    },
                    function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                    }
                );
            };

            request.send();

            }, 3000);

        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log('error: ' + error);
        });
```

This code is trow error of "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data" on `context.decodeAudioData` in chrome only.

What is wrong here and how can i fix it in chrome?

Here is working example in plunker: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/N8Ywg2YtX98m71LI4klC?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Ok... There is no fix for the issue. This is a chrome bug and you can see it [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=673782#)

The fix of decoding audio from MediaRecorder will be available on chrome version 58. I already tested it on 58-beta and it works.